# Unable to show the div on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This is my code posted in a [jsfiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jjfpy/4/)

As you can see when you click on the

- Hyderabad.
- Visakhapatnam.

Then a Horizontal Image slider is shown ( YOu can slide throgh the Pictures )

Now my requirement is I need to also show the Image slider on body load itself also

I have tried using  body `onload` function to show the div , and also in Jquery `ready` function , and by commenting all the `hide()` functions in javascript , but none of them really worked .

Could anybody please tell me what is the way to do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it.. first I thought that you should just do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $fp_galleries.first().click();
});
```

but poorly this will only show the first image and not all images.

I don't know why but it looks like you should do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jjfpy/5/).

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* your code */
    $fp_galleries.first().click();
});
```

Maybe because you need to wait until the images are loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much micha , i am strugling for this from morning . How can i integrate this code in my jsp , i mean i kept all the div section inside the body and all the script section inside the head tag part with <script> , but its not working . could you please help me

Comment: Thanks Micha that was a lot .

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use document on ready to call the function: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  openGallery(galleryname){
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it is hidden, its rather that the content are only generated by som javascript when the user clicks one of your links.

You could add something like

```
$("li",$fp_galleries).first().click()
```

at the bottom of your script.

This will trigger the click event on one of the links.